# String replacement in file only keeping the last change

Tags: powershell, loops, logic

```
        $injectpoint = %{ [Regex]::Matches($file, "DMG>D8>$dob.+?REF>EA>$mrn") } | %{ $_.Value }

        foreach ($data in $injectpoint)
        {
            $file = Get-Content C:\utils\foo\0000000.txt
            inject $file $eth $race $lang $data $dob 
        }
    }
}

function inject($file, $eth, $race, $lang, $injectpoint, $dob)
{
    Set-Location C:\utils\boo\
    $injector = "$race" + ":" + $eth + ":" + $lang
    $newString = $data -replace "DMG>D8>$dob", "DMG>D8>$dob>$injector"
    $file.Replace($data, $newString) | Set-Content C:\utils\foo\testfile.txt
}
```

My thought process is that because my loop re-reads the file into memory at the start of the loop it will have the new changes read into memory, where it will then be able to set new content without removing the changes my loop made in it's previous iteration.

I have tried to change where the file is read into memory (outside of loop, inside of inject function), but the current iteration is the furthest I got where I can see the last inject of my script, all other's are overwritten.

Comment: I'm probably just too dumb to comprehend what is going on, but I don't get it. You are reading `0000000.txt`, making changes to the read data, and then outputting the changes to `testfile.txt`. `testfile.txt` will have only the last thing changed by the last iteration of `$injectpoint`, which is what you don't like? And `Set-Content -Append` would keep all changes made by every iteration of `$injectionpoint`, which is also what you don't like? Also your function definition has an error because is has parameter `injectpoint` but actually uses `$data` in its script block.

Comment: @AdminOfThings I am an idiot, not you. I think I figured out the problem in my logic. I truly appreciate you asking that question.

I love you so much. Of course I wasn't going to get the info correctly because I wasn't saving the new changes to the old file. 

I have been staring at this for days, and I think I really just needed a fresh set of eyes.

Comment: @AdminOfThings if you want to post that I won't receive my data because I am saving it to a new file and not my old one, I will accept the answer. It is always the simplest solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is during your loop iteration, you are reading file `0000000.txt` and saving changes to `testfile.txt`. Since you never read `testfile.txt` after the string replacements, you don't see the updated strings.

Answer (score 0):

if i get you right you want add new content to file ***C:\utils\foo\testfile.txt***, for this you must use `Add-Content` cmdlet

Comment: Add-Content, will append the entire file to that file. What I want is for only the changes to the strings to stay, but they are currently getting overwritten. For more clarification, I am doing a lot of in-place string replacements saving the change and then going to the next replacement that needs to be made.

Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question however, I do appreciate it.

Comment: You read from one file `Get-Content C:\utils\foo\0000000.txt` then you did some changes in it and write content to another file `C:\utils\foo\testfile.txt` Can you explain what input and output you have< and what output you are wait? First file content in your script always same and set-content always rewrite your second file. Need explain what you want in output.